# How can you use conv.user.entitlements ? it returns an object but it doesn't show the data

Tags: actions-on-google

When I use conv.user.entitlements it returns "[ { entitlements: [ [Object] ], packageName: 'com.Company.ProjectName' } ]" to console.log -- is there a way to search the data in Object?

I tried conv.user.entitlements[entitlements], conv.user.entitlements.entitlements, and  conv.user.entitlements[0] thinking I can read it like an array but it didn't work and comes back undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried serializing it to see the structure, e.g.

```
console.log(`entitlements: ${JSON.stringify(conv.user.entitlements)}`);
```

Based on the structure posted in comments, accessing specific properties requires navigating through multiple arrays, e.g.:

```
console.log(entitlements[0].entitlements[0].inAppDetails);
```

`console.log(entitlements[0].entitlements[0].inAppDetails.inAppPurchaseData.purchaseTime);`

Comment: Thanks that does work. Can I access the individual elements
I tried var test123 = entitlements.inAppDetails.but it didn not work.
This is the returned object:
 [{
 "entitlements": [{
  "inAppDetails": {
   "inAppPurchaseData": {
    "purchaseToken": "*****",
    "productId": "premium",
    "orderId": "GAA.3308-9643-0749-88070",
    "purchaseTime": 1560638654200,
    "packageName": "com.company.product",
    "purchaseState": 0
   },
   "inAppDataSignature": "*****
  },
  "sku": "premium",
  "skuType": "IN_APP"
 }],
 "packageName": "com.company.product"
}]

Comment: Try: `console.log(entitlements[0].entitlements[0].inAppDetails);
    console.log(entitlements[0].entitlements[0].inAppDetails.inAppPurchaseData.purchaseTime);`